# Not able to access localhost:5000 with flask

Tags: python, flask

This a simple flask program

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

When i run it,

```
runfile('C:/Users/RB287JD/Documents/Programs/flask_1.py', wdir='C:/Users/RB287JD/Documents/Programs')
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But I am unable to access it, I tried http://localhost:5000/ and http://localhost:5000 , both gives me the same error

*Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

There are too many same questions here but none of them is clear to me. what is the actual problem here? i could able to access a day before but its not working now

Comment: have you tried app.run(host = '127.0.0.1') instead?

Comment: Don't give it a `host` argument.

Comment: then how should i give it ? app.run('0.0.0.0') ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not working. same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just call `app.run` to enable `flask` to automatically configure:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

Comment: Same error : runfile('C:/Users/RB287JD/Documents/Programs/flask_1.py', wdir='C:/Users/RB287JD/Documents/Programs')
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Answer (score 0):

Is this code being run externally from your computer?
If yes, you need the public IP address of where the flask app is being run from with :5000 on the end. E.g `22.22.222.222:5000`
If it is being run on your machine, try changing `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` to `app.run(host='localhost')` and connect to `http://localhost:5000` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive there is some issue with your loopback address .

Maybe you can try checking ip pf your machine .
Use  `ipconfig` on windows and `ifconfig`  on linux command prompt to see ip address of your machine 
And the use that IP in `app.run()`
E.g

```
app.run(host = 'your IP')
```

Then 
In browser use your IP:port see if this works

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue but when I got off my company's network and just ran from my home network, it started working.  Also I used the following command:

`app.run(host = '127.0.0.1')`

If you are experiencing this on your own network, you probably have some security setting prohibiting external code to be written to your computer.